# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, jar, gradle, android-studio, libraries

I am trying to adding .jar files to my android project (I am using Android Studio). Did everything that was explained here 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk I added a directory named libraries, copied the files in, and then compiled it.

my build.gradle looks like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':libraries')

}
```

my `settings.gradle` looks like this

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries'
```

But now I get the error `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your jar files inside the libs folder in your app module.
This line in the build.gradle file imports these files.

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

In the video, the libraries folder is a module, with a gradle.build file that you have to config.It isn't only a folder for jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Your module ":libraries" doesn't contain file "build.gradle" I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your project think the libraries is not a project or module, check the build.gradle under libraries, maybe you should replace

```
include ':libraries'
```

like this

```
include ':libraries:app'
```

and replace

```
compile project(':libraries')
```

like

```
compile project(':libraries:app')
```

the **app** is your module name.